# Add NT AUTHORITY\System to Sysadmin role in SQL Server outside the SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows

I'm having the problem, that I cannot restore a database programmatically because the setup file uses the account "NT-AUTHORITY\System" to restore it, which does not have sysadmin privileges.

Can I add it to the sysadmin like through editing the registry or through editing a file in SQL Server folder?

I'm using SQL Server Express 2019.

Or in other words, where are the privileges of users stored? So I can try to access them and edit them there.

I hope I can find help here.

Comment: Sounds like the file is in the wrong location, put the file in a location that the SQL Server Service account has access to. Alternatively, your SQL Server Instance should be running under an AD account that has access to the share you want to use (but still ensuring it has the minimal amount of permissions required).

Comment: thanks for your reply. Which file you mean? I tried to change the account of the sqlserver service but still the excution of the code happens with the user "NT-Authority\system". For your info, iam using a MSI Setup and this happens inside the installer class.

Comment: The backup file you're trying to restore; that's the only file mentioned in your question.

Comment: Normally a setup program would not restore a backup, but run a script to create a database from scratch in a clean state. This also avoids the filesystem permission problem previously mentiones. The setup, however, must ask the user for the account to use instead of hardcoding the system account.